# Swift: UITableView scrolls slowly when embedded in ContainerView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uicontainerview

I have two container views controlled by a segment controller. When the selected index changes, one view is set hidden and the other one is set visible.

One view contains a tableview, and the other one is a Google Maps view. I tried to remove the Google Maps view completely to see if the scrolling in the tableview would be better, and that fixed the laggy scrolling. So I know that it is the hidden mapView that makes the tableview scroll slowly.

My question is: How can I keep both container views and still have smooth scrolling when the tableView is visible? Setting the container view with the mapView to hidden does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this problem, try to follow this blog and add the views by code instead of using container views in IB. It fixed the problem, and the tableview now scrolls like a pro!

[cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/](https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/)